# Blocking all websites with exception list in Windows workgroup

Tags: windows, webfilter

How can I block all websites to certain users on a workgroup workstation except a specified list of sites running Windows 7 premium?

If possible I'd like the exception list to use wildcards like:

*.google. com

Preferably would like to use tools that are already built into Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Short of building a massive and ugly hosts file, you can't do what you want with the built-in Windows tools. The correct way to handle what you want to do is get an outbound proxy and force your network's traffic through it and handle the filtering there.